# Referencing another function in array of functions

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm using require.js and have a library of functions I use in multiple places. I define the functions thusly:

```
define(function (require) {

    "use strict";

    var $ = require('jquery');

    var UsefulFuncs = {};

    UsefulFuncs.hideAlert = function() {
        $('.alert').hide();
    };


    UsefulFuncs.loadURL = function (url){
            navigator.app.loadUrl(url, { openExternal:true });
            return false; 
    };


    UsefulFuncs.linkClicked = function (e) {    
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(e.currentTarget).attr("rel"); 
        this.loadURL(url);
    };


    return UsefulFuncs;

});
```

Then, in my backbone view, I call a function from the library with:

```
UsefulFuncs         = require('app/utils/useful_func'),

....

UsefulFuncs.linkClicked
```

This works fine for any standalone function in the library e.g. hideAlert(). However when one function in the library refers to another, such as linkClicked() calling loadURL(), I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'loadURL'.
```

Any ideas how I can reference loadUrl()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume you set `UsefulFuncs.linkClicked` as a handler for an event.

If you were to use it like this:

```
UsefulFuncs.linkClicked()
```

, `this` inside the function would refer to `UsefulFuncs`, so `this.loadURL()` would be valid.

However, since you set it as a handler for an event, it can be called in other ways, and `this` is set to some other object (probably the element which triggered the event). To avoid the event handling mechanism changing your `this`, you can bind the function when you assign it:

```
element.onclick = UsefulFuncs.linkClicked.bind(UsefulFuncs);
```

Another way to go around it is to avoid using `this` in the handler, like so:

```
UsefulFuncs.linkClicked = function (e) {    
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(e.currentTarget).attr("rel"); 
    UsefulFuncs.loadURL(url);
};
```

This creates a closure over `UsefulFuncs` (the first method does as well, but it's more standardized).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
define(function (require) {

    "use strict";

    var $ = require('jquery');

    var hideAlert = function() {
        $('.alert').hide();
    };


    var loadURL = function (url){
            navigator.app.loadUrl(url, { openExternal:true });
            return false; 
    };


    var linkClicked = function (e) {    
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(e.currentTarget).attr("rel"); 
        loadURL(url);
    };


    return {
        hideAlert : hideAlert,
        loadURL : loadURL,
        linkClicked : linkClicked
    };

});
```

Comment: I know it is a workaround, because it should work with 'this' too.